# how to improve Value Conversions performance in dotnet ef core?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use the [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) to convert an short[] into byte[] in dotnet ef core.

the table contains 10 short[] columns which saved as byte[] in database.
and the tables contains 10 million records. 
when I try to fetch all data from the database the timeout error exception have been raised.

My question is how can improve this conversion performance like making this conversion parallel or asynchronous or something else which make it possible to fetch all data faster.

Comment: You could make it parallel or increase timeout. Async normally does not make thinks faster.

Comment: do you have any idea how can i make it parallel?

Comment: Maybe the first question should be: why pull 10 million records from the database?

Comment: Another question should be: are you sure the problem is from conversions? What if you change the `int[]` properties to `byte[]` without conversion and try the same operation?

Comment: i need to compute some equation which need all data. and i test the efficiency of my convert which is about 0.05 millisecond for each conversions. also try to using the int[] but it takes no difference.